# Code formatting is missing from "about me" section on profile in Android app

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, android-app

@minitech's profile description on Stack Overflow is:

> Code formatting is `not` for emphasis!

However, the app is unable to show this, resulting in the quite humorous

[image]

Clicking the "expand" button (three dots) does nothing, probably because the about me section is too short to expand.

Strangely enough, the code formatting in my profile shows up correctly:

[image]

This is probably because my profile is long enough to need expanding, which somehow makes the app parse the markdown or something.

I would test the above theory or whether the bug also affects italics/bold/other formatting, but I don't have time to Do The Science™.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is simple: minitech's formatting in the profile is not usual SE code formatting, but the word is made of special chars.